# Javascript concatenado em input name

Tags: javascript, html, concatenação-de-string

Existe alguma forma de concatenar uma variável `javascript` junto a um `input`?

Esse `input hidden` eu submeteria junto a um formulário HTML

Como por exemplo:

```java
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strConcatenada = "STR_VARIAVEL.";
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="<%=strConcatenada%>W_TESTE_AUTO" value="1">
```

Comment: Que lingua de template é essa?

Comment: @Sergio esse exemplo seria em uma página html

Comment: Ok, e de onde vem `<%=`? estás a usar algum template-engine?

Comment: Justamente essa é minha duvida, procurei alguns exemplos e vi que usavam este formato `<%=`  para apresentar variáveis `javascript`, mas realmente não obtive sucesso desta forma

Comment: A resposta do Leonardo já explica como podes fazer. Em relação a essa sintaxe `<%=%>` isso é usado em templates. Muitas vezes no servidor. Mas agora já percebi que não sabes o que é, então podes tirar da pergunta pois só confunde :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você primeiramente tem que criar um ID para seu input, atribuir ele a uma variável:

`var element = document.getElementById("inputConcatenar");`

Depois você atribui ao `name` um novo valor, nesse caso eu usei o [Replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_replace.asp) que vai procurar uma string que você passar e substituir por outra.

```
element.name = element.name.replace("strConcatenada", strConcatenada)
console.log(element.name);
```

Fiz  da forma mais simples possível, o resultado é esse, segue o `console.log` do name. Caso você queira remover os "<% %>" basta passar **<%strConcatenada%>** para o Replace , ficando assim:

`replace("<%strConcatenada%>", strConcatenada)`

```html
<input id="inputConcatenar" type="hidden" name="<%=strConcatenada%>W_TESTE_AUTO" value="1">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var strConcatenada = "STR_VARIAVEL.";
    var element = document.getElementById("inputConcatenar");
    element.name = element.name.replace("strConcatenada", strConcatenada)
    console.log(element.name);
    
</script>
```

Comment: entendi e funcionou! hehe, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode executar um código javascript para alterar o nome ao carregar a página:

```
    <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
      <input type="hidden" name="_TESTE_AUTO" ID="_TESTE_AUTO" value="1">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
<script>
   var strConcatenada = "STR_VARIAVEL.";
   var input = document.getElementById("_TESTE_AUTO");
   input.name = strConcatenada + input.name;
</script>
```